# How do I set up a global error handler in WebApi?

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api

I am building a .NET WebApi application and I would like to set up a global error handler (basically a function that executes when an exception bubbles up from anywhere in the application). [this link](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1001) laments support for this, but several workarounds are offered. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find useful documentation for any of them.

Here are my requirements:

- Catch exceptions hit in action methods as well as in other places (e. g. controller resolution).
- Have access to the original Exception object during my handling.
- Have access to services in my (Autofac) IOC container during the error handling process (this is a strong want but not a must have).
- No dependency on MVC (I am using pure WebApi). No dependency on IIS is highly desirable.

How do I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 7):

If you update to Web API v2.1, available via Nuget with this command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi
```

You can create a Global Exception Handler by inheriting from Exception Logger.

Here is an example:

```
class TraceExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void LogCore(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(context.ExceptionContext.Exception.ToString());
    }
}
```

More details in the release notes here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21#global-error

Comment: any idea if this can be used for an MVC application as well?

Comment: You should post the full solution instead of linking to a page. This still needs to be called: `config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new TraceSourceExceptionLogger(new TraceSource("MyTraceSource", SourceLevels.All)));`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options you should be aware of:

Event **[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx)**:

Will fire for every exception no matter if it is handled. Use this for logging etc before your specific handler.

Event **[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx):**

Will Fire for every exception not handled in code

You would need to create handler in a service that has access to your IOC container etc

Comment: Will the UnhandlesExceptionHandler actually work when running on a web server or do thrown exceptions get swallowed by the underlying server?

Comment: From my testing, the UnhandledException handler never actually runs... seems like the underlying server is catching the exception somewhere.

Comment: I confess I havent tried in WebApi. Sorry this hasnt worked for you. Have you considered something like ELMAH https://code.google.com/p/elmah/. This provides very extensive exception logging. Here is an article how to integrate http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-api-and-elmah-integration

Comment: Based on that post, it seems like Elmah for WebApi uses ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext(), which uses HttpContext.Current, which (in my understanding) ties me to IIS.