# How to host WebApi only for processing request form a `MVC` project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

For this new project we decied to use `ASP.NET MVC 4` as our presentaional layer and `WebApi 2` as service layer. The idea is - when the user interacts with the UI and some request is send, the MVC controller is recieving this call, and if some sort of information for the response, a call is made from the MVC controller to the `WebApi` where the `WebApi` is entirely different solution, and in theory it may not be on the same place physically with the `MVC` solution.

For the MVC part I have this controller:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {

        return View("index", await GetUserAsync());
    }

    readonly string uri = "http://localhost:51120/api/user";

    protected async Task<List<User>> GetUserAsync()
    {

        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(
                await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri)
            );
        }
    }
```

Then I created an `ASP.NET Empty Web Application` solution. When the solution was created I installed `WebApi 2` from `Nuget` so I had a pretty basic structure of my project. I manually created the `Controllers`, `Models` and `Views` directories. In `Controllers` I have one file :

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public List<User> GetStringAsync()
    {
        return new List<User> {new User { Name = "Peter", Age = 41}};
    }
}
```

In `Models` I have this :

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And when I right click on the `View` folder I chose to install an `Empty view (without model)`. So basically that is my setup. When I start the solution I get this :

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory.
>
> Most likely causes: A default document is not configured for the
>   requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

And other stuff that I will post if neceessary. My question is - how can I do this. If I just create an MVC project with `WebApi` template I guess everything will work fine but then the whole point of doint this is missing. I want to be able to host the `WebApi` separately from the MVC solution, even physycally and only send and recieve calls.

Comment: Did you register the WebApi route(s) in the API project?

Comment: Nope, Literally all I did is described in my post. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You should have something like this: https://github.com/shanselman/ASP.NET-MVC-and-DbGeography/blob/master/SpatialFun/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs, or this: https://github.com/johnpapa/CodeCamper/blob/master/CodeCamper.Web/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: I get errors when I try to use `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute` and `routeTemplate` so I changed those with `routes.MapRoute` and `url` but still not working..

Comment: Assuming it is a routing issue (my first guess), you're best off creating a throw-away project using the full template. There are multiple WebApi packages, and I don't use WebApi enough to tell you what you need.

Comment: When verifying web api, you'll usually browse to something like /api/controller, not to the web app directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's totally valid response from the server because you don't have any routes configured. Routing is configured differently for MVC and Web API. You can read more about Web API routing [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions).

I think the easiest option for you will be to create a Web API project from a template. In VS2013 when you create new web ASP.NET Web Application you can choose which template to use. It's not possible to select only Web API without MVC. After you create a project you can see that there are two files in `App_Start` folder: `WebApiConfig` and `RouteConfig`. `RouteConfig` is routing for MVC. You can just delete this file and it's usage in `Global.asax`.

**EDIT**: As @EdSF mentioned you actually can create Web API project without MVC. Just select `Empty` template and check Web API check-box.

So your `WebApiConfig` will look like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

`MapHttpAttributeRoutes` is used to make [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) work and `MapHttpRoute` is similar to MVC. As you can see there is an `api` prefix, it's up to you if you want to use it or not. In general it's not a bad idea. For example if in the future you will have second version of your API you and you will need to keep first version too, then you can add new prefix `apiv2` or something like that.

If you don't like 403.14 response for root you can configure global handling for such situations. Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212725/how-to-catch-undefined-api-method-calls-in-asp-net-mvc4-web-api) for example.

Comment: _"It's not possible to select only Web API without MVC"_ - not true. You can absolutely create a Web API only project.

Comment: @EdSF Thanks for the comment. I updated the answer. I didn't know about these feature myself.

Comment: No biggie, your answer is actually very helpful to the OP (Web API Routing). Best ~

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the previous answer about not being able to create a `Web Api` project without MVC. You can absolutely do that and get what you want (a Web API only application):

1. New Project
2. Asp.Net Web Application
3. Empty
4. Check Web API (only)

---

After doing the above (which will already have the necessary default scaffolding), and copying your model, the only change to your controller:

```cs
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    //Handle GET request to /api/{controller name}
    public List<User> Get()
    {
        return new List<User> { new User { Name = "Peter", Age = 41 } };
    }
}
```

It's a Web API application so you won't have/need `Views`.

To invoke the above, via browser, browse to:

```
http://localhost:123456/api/user
```

Response:

```
<ArrayOfUser xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/StandAloneWebApi.Models">
   <User>
      <Age>41</Age>
      <Name>Peter</Name>
   </User>
</ArrayOfUser>
```

It's XML because I invoked it via a browser and am not "asking" for a specific response. If I set the `Accept` header to `application/json` I will get JSON.

e.g. using `curl`

```
curl -H "accept: application/json" http://localhost:123456/api/user
```

Response (edited for brevity):

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK    
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
....
[{"Name":"Peter","Age":41}]
```

The link in the Aleksandr Ivanov's answer will be very helpful and will give insight to how Web Api handles/routes requests.

Hth...

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a big time. One question if you have the time. I'm using `Visual Studio Express 2013 for web` and when I start `Nwe project -> ASP.NET Empty Web Application` on this step I don't see check for `WebApi` is this something missing in the `Express` version or I'm missing/making mistake on the steps?

Comment: @Leron Unfortunately I don't use/have Express...unsure if you're aware that [VS 2013 Community is free](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs) which gets you VS 2013 Pro features.