# exception handling in asp web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I wanted a method which caught all unhandled exceptions in my asp.net web api project. I found this post: [How do I log ALL exceptions globally for a C# MVC4 WebAPI app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167927/how-do-i-log-all-exceptions-globally-for-a-c-sharp-mvc4-webapi-app) which talks about using ExceptionFilterAttribute and OnException.

This is working so far, that i am able to catch an exception thrown in an api controller, and then identify the exception.
I would then like to throw a HttpResponseException with StatusCode and Content specific to the original exception i caught. How would i do this?

This is what i have so far:

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context) {
    HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage();
    if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(DBAccess.DeleteNotAllowed)) {
        msg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        msg.Content = new StringContent("Illegal action");
        msg.ReasonPhrase = "Exception";
        throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
    } else {
        //handle next exception type
    }
}
```

When a DeleteNotAllowed exception is thrown it is caught as intended and it's error message is sent to the client. However, another exception is thrown at the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is use Elmah.

It is one of the best tool that I have been using since 2010. It is the most useful tool for Exception handling. It will also give you a nice easy to use interface to view errors on web, e-amil and db.

for more details, please refer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/16/capturing-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net-web-api-s-with-elmah.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to translate all server side exceptions more human readable and meaningful ones? If this is what you want, then you have two options, write `if/else` or `try/catch` for all possible exception types, which will violate [OCP - Open Closed Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html)
, instead of this I suggest you this approach: Let each exception decide it's own "translation" for client, catch them in `OnException` and return to the client message and status code given by concrete exception.

```
    public class ApiException : Exception
    {
        public int FaultCode { get; private set; }

        public ApiException(int faultCode, string message)
            : base(message)
        {
            this.FaultCode = faultCode;
        }
    }
```

As you see it has `FaultCode` and `Message` (inherited from base `Exception`) properties, with it's constructor you require from each concrete implementer of `ApiException` to pass it's own status code and message(those you will translate later in `OnException` method).

```
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage();

        if (context.Exception is ApiException)
        {
            ApiException apex = context.Exception as ApiException;

            msg.StatusCode = apex.StatusCode;
            msg.Content = new StringContent(apex.Message);
            throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
        }
    }
```

And that's what your `OnException` method should look like.