# How to globally handle exceptions in asp.net web api when exception is raised through lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, lambda

I am having a global Exception handler in my web api project. This works fine except when the exception is raised through a lambda  expression. 
I have provided a sample code below:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
    //Throw new Exception();// this exception is handled by my ExceptionHandler
    var list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(1);
    IEnumerable<int> result = list.Select(a => GetData(a));
    return Ok(result);
}

private static int GetData(int a)
{
    throw new Exception();//This is not handled by my global exception handler
}
```

This is my global Exception Handler

```
public class ExceptionHandlerAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

I register it in my WebApiConfig class

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlerAttribute());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExceptionFilterAttribute` only works for exceptions thrown *in* your action method, see [Exception Handling in ASP.NET Web API - Exception Filters](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling#exception_filters). Your code will throw an exception during the materialization of the result, causing a `SerializationException`.

As explained in [Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling):

> Some unhandled exceptions can be processed via exception filters, but there are a number of cases that exception filters can’t handle. For example:
>
> - Exceptions thrown from controller constructors.
> - Exceptions thrown from message handlers.
> - Exceptions thrown during routing.
> - **Exceptions thrown during response content serialization**.

Register an exception handler or logger and act appropriately:

> We provide two new user-replaceable services, IExceptionLogger and IExceptionHandler, to log and handle unhandled exceptions. The services are very similar, with two main differences:
>   We support registering multiple exception loggers but only a single exception handler.
>
> 1. Exception loggers always get called, even if we’re about to abort the connection.
> 2. Exception handlers only get called when we’re still able to choose which response message to send.

See [this answer in How do I log ALL exceptions globally for a C# MVC4 WebAPI app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21252625/266143) for an implementation of both.

You can of course also materialize the enumerable in your controller, causing the exception to be thrown there and handled by the exception filter:

```
var result = list.Select(a => GetData(a)).ToList();
```