# Automate an already running Visual Studio instance by using devenv on developer command prompt

Tags: visual-studio, automation, devenv

devenv C:\Users\Alxe\Desktop\newFolder\Console.cpp /command "GotoLn 25"

The above command when executed, will launch the visual studio IDE and open Console.cpp file and go to Line 25, what I wanted is to open console.cpp file on an already running Visual studio instance(assuming that project folder has console.cpp file) and go to Line 25. Is there other way to do it?

My motive was to run a .bat file having the commands above from another application.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116286/how-can-i-programmatically-launch-visual-studio-and-send-it-to-a-specific-file

Comment: The link you gave created an instance of Visual studio IDE, I am able to do that, but what I really want is to access an already running instance of Visual studio IDE and automate that instance.

Comment: For an already running Visual Studio instance see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205933/how-do-i-get-the-dte-for-running-visual-studio-instance